# Create constructor for generic class using reflection

Tags: reflection, constructor, c#-2.0

I want to create a class using reflection for a generic class.

Could someone tell me how to create it?

I have

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
  ....
}
```

I need to create a class for `SomeClass<T>` using reflection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method:

```
Type myParameterizedSomeClass = typeof(SomeClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyParameter));
ConstructorInfo constr = myParameterizedSomeClass.GetConstructor(typeof(ConstrParamType1),typeof(ConstrParamType2));
```

Comment: Thanks, i was tagged this in C#.2.0 version. Is it possible in that?

Comment: @Raj I am reasonably certain that it is. Did you try it?

Comment: @Raj Did you try the updated answer? It should work in C#2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to instantiate an existing class using reflection of create a new class in runtime? 
If it's the former :

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("SomeClass");
SomeClass<String> sc =  (SomeClass<String>)c.newInstance();
```

If it's the latter, check out [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). Haven't tried it but it looks easy to use.
I'm assuming you are using Java.

Comment: No. It is tagged as c#